# Cannot connect to mysql server Error: mysqld.sock' (38)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am working on ruby on rails project. after setting up all environment for the project but when I run localhost:3000 on my web browser it gives my this error

`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (38)`

Can someone help me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the server turned on? MySQL by default runs on port 3306 are you sure yours runs on 3000?

Comment: yes mysql is turned on. I dont know on which port mysql is running

Comment: how can I find that mysql is running on which port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails by default tries to connect to MySQL using a socket file. You probably want it to connect using a TCP connection.

Check your **database.yml**; it should look similar to this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  host: localhost
  database: {database name}
  pool: 5
  username: {username}
  password: {password}
```

Notice the `host` parameter and the missing `socket` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Check if mysql is running

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```